# Реализация своего интерфейса под способы оплаты | laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ооп, платежи

Всем привет! Возникла необходимость реализовать добавление оплаты различными способами. На данный момент есть лишь 1 метод в PaymentController@store:

```
 public function store(StorePaymentRequest $request)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $order = Order::findOrFail($request->order_id);
            $order->status_id = 2;
            $order->save();
            $order->payments()->create([
                'payment_type' => $request->payment_type,
                'amount' => $request->amount,
                'created_at' => $request->created_at ? Carbon::parse($request->created_at)->toDateTimeString() : Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                'status' => 1
            ]);
            event(new OrderPaid($order));
            DB::commit();
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Payment successfully stored']);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            return response()->json(['error' => 'System error.', 'message' => $e->getMessage()], 400);
        }
    }
```

После реализации способов оплаты, сервер должен принимать запросы от платежных систем со статусами оплаты. Понимаю, что нужно:

- создать интерфейс `IPayment`, который будут наследовать классы, написанные под каждый способ оплаты.
- добавить реализацию интерфейса через IoC в контроллеры

В идеале, вижу код каждого метода контроллера таким:

```
public function yandexCashier(YandexCashierService $service, Request $request)
{
  try {
    $service->storePayment($request);
  } catch(\PaymentException $e) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Является ли данный подход правильным и как его лучше всего реализовать? Подобное делаю в первый раз, поэтому очень интересно мнение сообщества.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сервис внедряйте через конструктор контролллера, присвойте приватной переменной ваш сервис, потом можете пользоваться в методе таким образом:

```
private $yandexCashierService;

public function __construct(YandexCashierService $yandexCashierService)
{
   $this->yandexCashierService = $yandexCashierService;
}

public function yandexCashier(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $this->yandexCashierService->storePayment($request);
    } catch(\PaymentException $e) {
      ...
    }
}
```